# Toasting chopped almonds

Tags: roasting, almonds

I want to add chopped toasted pecans to my stove top stuffing.  How do I toast 1/4 cup of chopped almonds?

Comment: Are you toasting almonds or pecans?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to toast pecans?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29351/what-is-the-best-way-to-toast-pecans)

Comment: Benefit of the doubt: we are talking about a) chopped nuts and b) a small amout where the potential duplicate needs a lot more for a pie filling.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference to the linked question is that we are talking about chopped nuts (pecans or almonds isn't much of a difference, the same principle applies) and only a small amount.

You could fire up your oven, but chopped nuts tend to dry and burn much quicker and for a tiny amount like 1/4 cup, heating up the oven sounds like overkill. You *can* use the [oven method described here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/29351/what-is-the-best-way-to-toast-pecans), but need to watch like a hawk to prevent scorching them. But for a small amount, a pan is just fine.

- So get a small frying pan (non-stick would be good here but not mandatory) and heat it on medium heat on the stove. Do not add oil or anything else.
- Add the copped nuts and *keep stirring* or flipping until they are fragrant and some start getting darker. Use your nose and eyes to determine when they are done.
- As soon as your nuts have reached the desired roasting stage, *remove them from the pan* and pour them on a cool plate.